# Android - SOS APP

Tags: android

So, in my app I got a SOS button to make a call to whoever you assigned to be your SOS target. And I want it to make the all and when the call ends it must go back to the activity I was in the APP.

Any tips you guys can give me ?

Comment: I think we need code, explanation, something to understand what you need.

Comment: I did something like that in an app of mine (a lifesaver call feature). You will need the permission `android.permission.CALL_PHONE` and a little code. (Plus the code to read from your contacts and save it as a preference).

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't provide any code, the basic approach could be:

```
    public static void callNumber(String number,Activity activity){
    String uri =  "tel:"+number.trim();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse(uri));
    activity.startActivityForResult(intent,someIntegerCodeYouChoose);

}
```

And add to your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
```